# How to define a vector with undefined size

Tags: c++, vector, size

I am a beginner and I want to write a loop in cpp in which a vector has unknown size which is determined by a if funcion.
basically I want to convert this MATLAB code to cpp code:

```
v(1)=A(1);
for i=2:length(A)
     if (abs((A(i)-v))>10^(-5))
       v=[v;A(i)];      
     end
end
```

It is clear in the code that the size of v is not determined before the loop starts, how can I write this code in cpp?

Comment: how about std::vector?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/

Comment: Why you want to go for something *undefined*, C++ already has enough of it!

Comment: You would have a dimension mismatch with `A(i)-v` as soon as `v` gets a second element.  Did you mean `v(end)` or `A(i-1)`?

Answer (score 5):

In C++, if we want a container of values that we can add values to and it expands at run-time, we use an `std::vector`. As you can see, it is aptly named for your purpose. The matlab line `v=[v;A(i)];`, which concatenates a value from `A` with `v`, is equivalent to using the [`std::vector::push_back`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) function: `v.push_back(A[i]);`.

Answer (score 2):

The standard C++ library has a class [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) as indicated by one of the comments. The `vector` class doesn't have a pre-defined size; as you add member objects, the size of the vector grows dynamically. It might be worthwhile to read about standard C++ library in general and vector in particular.

Answer (score 1):

Following code can be used to define vector of undefined size.

```
vector<string> v;
```

Remember that, for `<string>` you need following header file:

```
#include<string>
```

After all this you can push elements using `push_back()` function as follows-

```
v.push_back('a');
v.push_back('b');
v.push_back('c');
v.push_back('c');
```

There are some other useful functions for vectors you can give watch into-

```
front();
back();
begin();
end();
rbegin();
rend();    
max_size();
capacity();
resize();
empty();
at(n);
```

Read details of these function and their usage.